# Finding start and end time from timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I was facing problem (details cane be found here: [calculating total time using timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702014/calculating-total-time-using-timestamp#)) few months ago about finding time **duration** from a mysql table where it has only **1** or **0** value representing **open** or ***closing*** status of a door. The table seems like this :

**1) TABLE t**

```
id   binary   timestamp

2888    1     2015-05-21 18:01:58
2888    1     2015-05-21 18:01:47
2889    1     2015-05-21 17:58:06
2888    0     2015-05-21 18:01:40
2889    1     2015-05-21 17:57:39
2888    1     2015-05-21 18:01:34
2888    0     2015-05-21 18:01:26
2889    1     2015-05-21 17:58:25
2889    0     2015-05-21 17:57:22
2889    1     2015-05-21 17:58:19
2889    1     2015-05-21 17:57:22
2889    0     2015-05-21 18:03:57
2889    1     2015-05-21 17:58:13
1889    1     2015-05-21 18:03:49
2889    1     2015-05-21 18:03:42
2889    1     2015-05-21 18:03:35
```

Thanks `fancyPants` and `gRaWEty` for helping me to slve that.

Well, I was using the code for calculating time **duration** is:

**2) SQL QUERY**

```
    select
    id, `binary`,
    sec_to_time(count(distinct `timestamp`))
    from
    t
    where 
    `timestamp` between concat(curdate(), ' 00:00:00') 
    and
    concat(curdate(), ' 23:59:59')
    group by id, `binary`
```

so, what the output I was getting is like this:

**3) OUTPUT**

```
id     binary      duration

1889    1          00:00:01
2888    0          00:00:02
2888    1          00:00:03
2889    0          00:00:02
2889    1          00:00:08
```

> > (well, even if someone ignore all text and just go through 1)-2)-3) hopefully will get a clear picture)

Everything was fine as long I just needed to calculate **duration** only, now the problem occurs when I was asked to **show starting_time(stamp)** and **ending_time(stamp)** beside **duration**. Because I am going to make a timeline which need a table like this:

**4) OUTPUT (I'm looking for)**

```
  id    binary  start_time            end_time              duration

1889    1       2015-05-21 18:03:49   2015-05-21 18:03:49   00:00:01
2889    1       2015-05-21 18:03:35   2015-05-21 18:03:42   00:00:08
```

What I mean here is, if you look at the **1) TABLE t**, the door 1889 was open for 1sec from `2015-05-21 18:03:49` to `2015-05-21 18:03:49`. The door 2889 was open for 8sec from `2015-05-21 18:03:35` to `2015-05-21 18:03:42`. My code can generate only this duration (8sec) as of output **3)** , but I am looking for the time it was open for , with two additional column, in this case would be `2015-05-21 18:03:35` as ***start_time*** and `2015-05-21 18:03:42` as ***`end_time`*** as of output **4)**

**Now my questions:**

> 1. what should be the code to get output (as no. 4) with **start_time** and **end_time**?
> 2. is it possible save my output as a table (like with column named ***id***, ***binary***, ***start_time***, ***end_time***, ***duration***) in mysql database?
>
> > if yes, could anyone provide link or sample code for that?

THANKS IN ADVANCE :)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: I think I should add some lines to My existing code, cant figure out exactly how? sorry to bother,  could you be more specific. I am really nerd maybe

Comment: `select .... sec_to_time(timestampdiff(start_time, end_time))`, basically. `timestampdiff` will subtract your two datetimes and give you a difference in seconds, and `sec_to_time` will take those seconds and format it as `hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: Thanks again dude. but sorry, first of all I couldn't run the code successfully (might be my fault). secondly, I checked the link you provided, if I am not wrong, maybe it's not what I am looking for. as I understood, timestampdiff is generating time difference only, like how many days, months or sec. but i am looking for the start & end time too for that time duration..well, i just edited my post, hope it will make more clear :)

Comment: Does id column is an id of each open-close cycle or id of a door? In the second case your code for calculating time duration is wrong because it gives only 1 value for every (id,binary) pair

Comment: id column represents the sensor id, I have several sensors and each of them have id. for example 2889 is the sensor set on the door, while 1889 set on the window. sorry for late reply. @AlexanderUshakov